# Swift: How to check if user's phone number is already in Firebase database before creating a new user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just started working with `Swift` a few months ago and to help me learn the language better, I am creating a chat application. For the sign-in method, I am using the phone number method. I have the onboarding process already created but I want to implement something that lets me check if the user has already created an account with that phone number. If they have, I want to segue them to the main view controller, skipping the onboarding view controller.

Here is my code for the phone verification view controllers (One is for inputting a phone number and the other is for inputting the code sent to the user's phone):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class PhoneVerification: UIViewController {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var code: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var verifyCodeImage: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sendCodeImage: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    //MARK: Format phone text field
    var phoneFormatter = PhoneNumberFormatter()
    @IBAction func formatPhoneNumber(_ sender: UITextField) {
        sender.text = phoneFormatter.format(sender.text!, hash: sender.hash)
    }

    //MARK: When send secret code button is pressed

    @IBAction func sendCode(_ sender: Any) {
        let submitPhoneNumber = "+1" + phoneNumber.text!
        if submitPhoneNumber.count > 9{
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(submitPhoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) {(verificationID, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            }else{
                UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "phoneCode", sender: self)
            }
        }
        }else{
            let phoneNumAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Please enter your phone number", message: "You must enter your phone number to continue.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            phoneNumAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

            self.present(phoneNumAlert, animated: true)
        }
    }
    let verificationID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authVerificationID")

    //MARK: When verify code button is pressed
    @IBAction func verifyCode(_ sender: Any) {
        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
            withVerificationID: verificationID!,
            verificationCode: code.text!)

        //This is where the user is signed in if the verification code is correct
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {

                let invalidCodeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "That code is incorrect", message: "Please input the correct code", preferredStyle: .alert)

                invalidCodeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

                self.present(invalidCodeAlert, animated: true)
                print(error)
                return
            }
                //MARK: User is signed in
                print("Phone number: \(String(describing: user?.phoneNumber))")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "accountCreated", sender: self)
        }
    }

}
```

All help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: hi, did you find a solution to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you hold user data at the `users` ref. When the user signs in check to see if they have any data there, if they do then they are an existing user, if they don't then it is a new account:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { [weak self](authDataResult, error) in

    if let error = error { return }

    guard let safeAuthDataResult = authDataResult else { return }

    // 1. get the signed in user's userId
    let userId = safeAuthDataResult.user.uid

    // 2. check to see if their userId exists at the user's path
    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId)
    usersPublicDataRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        // 3. this is a new user
        if !snapshot.exists() {

            // *** what you should do here is update the user's ref with some sort of data

        } else {

            // 4. this is an existing user
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FirebaseAuthUI** and **FirebasePhoneAuthUI** to registered your mobile number into firebase. It's default method and UI which is provided by Firebase itself. So you don't have to worry about rest of things.

You just have to installed PhoneAuthUI using pod and write down below code to registered mobile number:

```
    FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.delegate = self
    let phoneProvider = FUIPhoneAuth.init(authUI: FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!)
    FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.providers = [phoneProvider]
    let currentlyVisibleController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController
    phoneProvider.signIn(withPresenting: currentlyVisibleController!, phoneNumber: nil)
```

Once your mobile number is registered then you will get a callback on this method:

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {
    if user != nil{
        // here we need to check if current user is registered or not.
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }else if error != nil{
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

For more information, you can see [this tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/05/firebase-phone-auth.html).

Comment: Ok so I installed the PhoneAuthUI pod like you said to but I am still a little confused regarding where I would put that code in my view controller class. Any clarification would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This is code which help to registered your mobile number into firebase. So you can call my first part of code when you want to registered. Once FirebaseUI register mobile number, delete method is called.